# terraforming templatefile with for and escape last comma

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I am creating an AWS Stack Set (at org level) which is written in cloud formation. For the cloud formation, it is written in a terraform template file so that variables are passed from terraform. However there one part which I am having issues with.

The `for` section needs to look the principals and create `Principal` block in the template. However the last index of the loop contains a comma which will makes the stack template invalid.

Is there away in terraform to prevent the last comma in a loop?

main.tf:

```
variable "cross_account" {
  type = list(object({
    principals  = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      principals  = ["ACCOUNT_ID1","ACCOUNT_ID2","ACCOUNT_ID3"]
    }
  ]
}
output "test" {
  value = templatefile("./json.tpl", {
    principals = var.cross_account[0].principals
  })
}
```

Template file (json.tpl):

```
"Principal": {
"AWS": [
  %{ for princ in principals ~}
      {
        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${princ}:root"
      }
  , # <--------------- Need to prevent this line on the last loop index
  %{ endfor ~}
]
```

I have shorten the code down to only the bits needed above. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html):

```
"Principal": {
"AWS": ${jsonencode([
  for princ in principals:
      {
        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${princ}:root"
      }
])}
```

Or you can use it for all template as shown [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template) depending how exactly your template is defined.

Comment: Tried updating the json.tmp and terraform it not happy with `${` in template files:
`Call to function "templatefile" failed: ./json.tpl:9,1-2: Extra characters after interpolation expression; Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra characters.`

Comment: @TD4091433 Please check again. The code  works. You either used it incorrectly or your question is not representative of your real code.

Comment: I have tried different options, I've tried updating the json.tpl with your code, but because it not terraform it does not like `${` which is why you have to use `%{`. I also tried updating the main.tf with 

```
output "test" {
  value = templatefile("./json.tpl", {
    principals = jsonencode([
      for princ in var.cross_account[0].principals:
      {
        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${princ}:root"
      }
    ])
  }
}
```
and its not liking `"Fn::Sub":`. It actually gives the following error: `│ A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.`

Comment: @TD4091433 Sorry, can you clarify what is not a terraform? Also what is `jsonencode([ for princ in var.cross_account[0].principals:`? This does not match your question, which means you are using different code that you posted.

Comment: I only made that code change based on the link you sent trying to generate it from json template, ignore that for now.

`json.tpl` is not terraform file (.tf) it is a templatefile which is loaded from terraform `main.tf` on this line `value = templatefile("./json.tpl",`.  The change you provided breaks the templating as `${` is not allowed in that file.

Comment: @TD4091433  I executed your code. It works perfectly fine. `json.tpl` is valid code. The only thing you have to do is copy-and-paste my json.tpl for yours. Nothing else. It will work with the code you have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for a while with the help of @Marcin, was able to get a working code:

main.tf:

```
variable "cross_account" {
  type = list(object({
    principals  = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      principals  = ["ACCOUNT_ID1","ACCOUNT_ID2","ACCOUNT_ID3"]
    }
  ]
}

output "test" {
  value = templatefile("./json.tpl", {
    principals = jsonencode([for i in var.cross_account[0].principals: tomap({"Fn::Sub" = "arn:aws:iam::${i}:root"})])
  })
}
```

Template file (json.tpl):

```json
"Principal": {
"AWS":  ${principals}
}
```

results in the following without the extra comma:

```
test = <<-EOT
        "Principal": {
        "AWS":  [{"Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID1:root"},{"Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID2:root"},{"Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID3:root"}]
        }
    EOT
```